# How to replace the last line in stringbuilder

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

Since there is a way to append line to the string builder object (using `AppendLine()`), is there any direct way to find the particular line without having to hard code the new line character `\n`?

So basically I want to replace the last line text of the string builder object in which I added lines using `AppendLine` method.

Is there any way?
I found there are ways to find the last line in string using `\n` but not string builder

Answer (score 2):

I think more useful extension will be to return StringBuilder as result.

So, if you want to know aboun StringBuilder, see it's [code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs,adf60ee46ebd299f)

```
public static class StringBuilderExt
{
    public static StringBuilder RemoveLastLine(this StringBuilder sb)
    {
        for (int i = sb.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (Environment.NewLine.Contains(sb[i]))
            {
                sb.Remove(i, sb.Length - i);
                return sb;
            }
        }
        return sb;
    }
}
```

And you can use this extension, with no breake builder pattern:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine("First line")
            .AppendLine("Second line")
            .AppendLine("Last line");
        Console.WriteLine(sb);

        sb.RemoveLastLine().AppendLine("Line after delete last line");

        Console.WriteLine(sb);
    }

}
```

And you will see result:

```
First line
Second line
Last line

First line
Second line
Line after delete last line
```

Comment: You also need to consider \r as new line on Windows is \r\n and not just \n. If you only remove the latter you leave a dangling \r. Or better, use Environment.NewLine to check which characters to remove, which would also make the code more self-documenting and not use “magic values”.

Comment: Should be `Environment.NewLine.Contains(sb[i])` as Environment.NewLine is a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an extension method that let's you find the last index of a given char in a `StringBuilder`:

```
public static class StringBuilderExtensions
{
    public static int LastIndexOf(this StringBuilder sb, char character)
    {
        for(int i = sb.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if(sb[i] == character)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Now you can remove the last character (which is `\n` when you just added a line), and then search for the last `\n` and remove everything from there. After that, you can add any new line which leads to replacing the last line:

```
sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
int index = sb.LastIndexOf('\n') + 1;
sb.Remove(index, sb.Length - index);
sb.AppendLine("new content");
```

Of course, you can also put this code into an extension method like `ReplaceLastLine`. Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0dVyej